# Azure SpeechSynthesizer Error HTTP: not supported. Expected HTTPS: NPM `microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk`

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, npm, azure-cognitive-services

I am using the **microsoft-congnitiveservices-speech-sdk** npm package and things have been working fine.  But randomly I am getting an error now.  Either broke with browser update or minor package update(?)

```
'Unable to contact server. StatusCode: 500, undefined Reason: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL]: Protocol "http:" not supported. Expected "https:"'
```

I have tried from both a local dev HTTP server, as well as a production site that is secure with HTTPS.  Any thoughts or solutions to solve what is being the microsoft-congnitiveservices-speech-sdk issue?

```
import * as Azure from "microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk";

const speechConfig = Azure.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(SPEECH_KEY, SPEECH_REGION);
      speechConfig.speechSynthesisOutputFormat = Azure.SpeechSynthesisOutputFormat.Audio48Khz192KBitRateMonoMp3;

const synthesizer = new Azure.SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig);

const ssml = `
  <speak version="1.0" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xml:lang="en-US">
    <voice name="en-US-JennyNeural">
      <prosody volume="85" pitch="medium" rate="1">
        <break time="1.5s" /> ${text}
      </prosody>
    </voice>
  </speak>
`

try {
  synthesizer.speakSsmlAsync(
    ssml,
    result => {
        synthesizer.close();
        console.log('RESULT', result)
        resolve(result);
    },
    error => {
        synthesizer.close();
        console.log('ERROR', error)
        if(error) throw Error(error)
    });
}
catch(err) {
  console.log(err)
  throw(err)
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am Yulin, an engineer in Microsoft TTS team. Sorry for the late reply. Your codes looks good and the error massage is weird, as the SDK will always try to use https or wss endpoint. Could you share me minor repro so I can help to debug?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, this message showed up all the sudden without code/dependency change

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was related to Sentry integration. More info here: https://github.com/microsoft/cognitive-services-speech-sdk-js/issues/458

So far seems like issue is not resolved.